# Является ли "невероятно" вводным словом?

Tags: синтаксис, вводные-слова

*Я не верил этому до конца. Он ещё вчера был совершенно невоспитанным. Невероятно, но он изменился!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, слово ***невероятно*** не является вводным. Словари не приводят такого значения (да и невозможно представить себе структуру, где это было бы приемлемо):

[**невероятно**](https://xn----8sbauh0beb7ai9bh.xn--p1ai/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE) (Ефремова Т. Ф. Толковый словарь русского языка),
[**невероятно**](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE) (Викисловарь).

> *в знач. сказуемого* оценочная характеристика ситуации, чьих-либо действий как представляющихся невозможными, не соответствующими действительности, неправдоподобными...

Отрицательная приставка НЕ не дает возможности использовать это слово в качестве вводного, в отличие от его пары: [**ВЕРОЯТНО**, *вводное слово*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_269) (Грамота.ру).
Если мы исключим ***невероятно*** из предложения, как это можно сделать с вводными словами, то, казалось бы, связь с предыдущим контекстом не потеряется: *Он ещё вчера был совершенно невоспитанным. Но он изменился!* Однако в данном случае это не играет роли. Если переставить в другое место, то ***невероятно*** станет просто обстоятельством: *Но он невероятно изменился!*

Наш случай – сложносочиненное предложение, в котором первое простое предложение состоит из одного слова (сказуемого) и является неполным: *[Это] невероятно...*

**Примеры из Нацкорпуса:**

*Невероятно, но это факт, и я ещё раз подтверждаю, что...* [Д. А. Гранин. Месяц вверх ногами (1966)]

*Невероятно, но меня обставили… Вот ведь невезуха!* [Евгений Лукин. Клопики (2013)]

*Это было невозможно, невероятно, но это случилось.* [Альберт Валентинов. Разорвать цепь // «Техника - молодежи», 1977]

*Как говорится, невероятно, но факт, а факты ― упрямая вещь.* [Мозаика // «Знание - сила», 1997]

Answer (score 3):

Никакое это не вводное слово, а наречие, если я правильно понимаю.

> (Это) невероятно, но он изменился.

И возьмите ещё на заметку, что за вводным словом не может сразу следовать "но", если только оно не поясняет само вводное слово и не относится к продолжению мысли (в то время как вводное относится к предыдущей части).

Comment: Можете привести пример, когда "но" будет пояснять вводное?

Comment: Спасибо за вопрос, я сам усомнился в том, нормальны ли такие примеры. Имел в виду что-то типа "По его словам (но вопреки здравому смыслу), праздник начался ещё глубокой ночью". Просьба ко всем навести критику на этот пример или одобрить его — как он того заслуживает. ;)

Comment: Артём, я тоже не понял про пояснение (о примере подумаю). А еще, считаю, нужно уточнить, что *за вводным словом не может сразу следовать "но"*, только если вводное стоит в начале предложения

Comment: Спасибо, Александр, сейчас я сделаю дополнение.

Comment: Берем вводное "В ОБЩЕМ И ЦЕЛОМ", и запихиваем туда "но" вместо "и": НЕ В ОБЩЕМ, НО ЦЕЛОМ

Comment: В данном предложении «наверное» не является наречием.

Comment: @JimKorbett: вы о "невероятно"? И что же это, по-вашему?

Answer (score 0):

В данном предложении «невероятно» — краткое прилагательное, сокращенное от слова «невероятное».
Это слово может быть наречием, например, в таком предложении: «Он боксировал невероятно».